# Competing-Consumers Messaging Pattern in Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm just getting started with Windows Azure Service Bus (*Topics & Queues*) and I'm trying to implement a Competing-Consumers messaging pattern.

Essentially, I want to have a set of message **Producers** and a set of message **Consumers**. Once a message is produced, I want the first available Consumer to process the message. No other Consumers should get the message.

Is there a way to do this in Azure?

Comment: What kind of/how much work is behind each message? What are your time constraints?

Comment: @Simon Ideally Consumers would start processing a message within 10-30ms of the time the message is Produced. If Producers are out-pacing Consumers, I will add more Consumers to meet demands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want Topics then, but rather [Brokered Messaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh367512.aspx).

You can emulate Topic-like functionality in Brokered Messaging by using the message's Label and/or Content Type properties along with the [PeekLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.receivemode.aspx) receive mode.

Comment: Does that mean I just create a queue; setting the ReceiveMode as appropriate; and bind all consumers to the same queue? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you use the PeekLock method, then you will be able to inspect the Label or ContentType to see if it's a type of message that the receiver wants to respond to. If it is, just call .Complete() on the message, if not, then .Abandon(). Once abandoned, and the short lock expires, other consumers of the queue can process the message. If it's completed, then it's permanently removed from the queue.

Answer (score 6):

Simple. Just make two (or more) receivers that concurrently receive from a single queue and you're done. Any retrieved message goes to exactly one of those receivers since the cursor over the mesasage log is advanced as a message is taken. Competing consumers are an inherent capability of a networked queue so there's really nothing special needed.

If you need the opposite - each message goes to each consumer - you make a subscrioption per consumer which gives you an isolated cusor over the message log that can move independent of other receivers. For kicks, you can obviously also have competing consumers on a subscription.

Clemens

Comment: Not sure I see how you can have competing consumers on a subscription.  Would this be done using a filter?  Can you explain a little further or point to more info?

Answer (score 4):

Topics are a feature of brokered messaging, but are a one-to-many "publish/subscribe" pattern. Queues are one-to-one message communication. So yes, it sounds like you should simply use queues. Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh689723(VS.103).aspx.

Comment: Queues are one-to-one message communication in the sense that the message will be delivered to one receiver. However, nothing prevents you from having multiple receivers listening on the same queue at the same time to enable the scenario you mention.